# "Kugel des Glücks". What is it?

Tags: person-names

Bei der Lektüre von Klabunds Geschichte "Der sterbende Soldat" habe ich zwei Sätze entdeckt, die ich nicht verstanden habe:

(1) Tag und Nacht sind nicht mehr. Sind versunken wie Segelschiffe hinterm Horizont des Meeres. Ich weiß nicht mehr von Tag und Nacht. Von Sonne und von den grauen Krähen der Dämmerung. Von der Erde und von der runden ***Kugel des Glücks***.

Was bedeutet "Kugel des Glücks"?

(2) Es muß irgendwo neben oder unter mir liegen. Worauf soll ich nun reiten? Ich werde auf einem toten Engländer in die Hölle reiten. Aber ***Lilli*** will es nicht. Sie faßt meine Hand, ich bin ja blind, und wird mit mir den Himmel suchen gehen. Lilli, sag' ich, hier riecht es nach Veilchen, hier ist der Himmel. Sie läßt meine Hand los.

Der Protagonist sagt, dass sein Pferd tot ist. Der nächste Satz handelt von einer gewissen Lilli. Ist das seine Freundin oder ist das der Spitzname seines Pferdes?

Comment: Das wird eine Mozartkugel sein. ;)

Answer (score 2):

1.) Der ganze Text ist stark bewusstseinsströmend (Ist das ein Wort? *Stream of consciousness*). Ohne weitere Anhaltspunkte kann man nur raten. Es muss jedenfalls etwas sein, dass für den Soldaten in der Vergangenheit wichtig war. Bei „Kugel des Glücks“ drängt sich mir die Verbindung zum Glücksspiel, *Roulette*, auf. Andererseits sind Rad oder Kugel seit der Antike typische Symbole für die div. Gottheiten des Geschickes (Fortuna etc.); im Mittelalter entstand die Vorstellung von einem Rad oder einer Kugel des Glückes. Das ist hier sicherlich nicht wörtlich zu verstehen, aber als „Schicksal“ oder „Weltenlauf“ im übertragenen Sinn könnte es passen.

2.) Wer Lilli ist oder war wissen wir ebenfalls nicht, aber mit Sicherheit nicht sein Pferd (vgl. Lilli will es nicht. Sie faßt meine Hand … Sie läßt meine Hand los.) wohl eine Frau, Freundin oder sonstige weibliche Bezugsperson. Details bleibt uns Klabund schuldig.

Comment: [Bewusstseinsstrom](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bewusstseinsstrom) + -en + -d, also ja. Aber ist "Der ganze Text bewusstseinsströmt stark" nicht grammatikalischer? :)

Comment: Thank you for the comment! That's a real explanation!

Comment: Was ist "bewusstseinsströmend" (or even in English, a "stream of consciousness")? That sound extremely esoteric at least

Comment: Tante Wiki meint: *Bewusstseinsstrom (englisch stream of consciousness) bezeichnet die ungeregelte Folge von Bewusstseinsinhalten. In der Literaturwissenschaft ist damit eine Erzähltechnik gemeint, die die scheinbar ungeordnete Folge der Bewusstseinsinhalte einer oder mehrerer Figuren wiedergibt. Bekannte Beispiele sind … Lieutenant Gustl von Arthur Schnitzler, Ulysses von James Joyce und Virginia Woolfs Die Wellen.* Der Autor lässt uns quasi ungefiltert an den Gedanken seines Protagonisten teilhaben.

Comment: Könnte es nicht einfach der Mond sein?

Comment: @userunknown: Was jetzt? Mozartkugel oder Mond? Wenn du es nicht weißt, lass bitte solche unsinnigen Kommentare, die helfen niemandem. Im Gegenteil: sie stiften nur noch mehr Verwirrung.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Kannst Du Smilies entziffern?

Answer (score 2):

In den Gedanken des sterbenden Soldaten mischen sich Realität ud Traumbilder. Hier einige [Zitate](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Klabund/Erz%C3%A4hlungen/Der+Marketenderwagen/Der+sterbende+Soldat):

- Wir marschieren bei Tag. Wir marschieren bei Nacht. Wir schlafen in der Nacht. Wir schlafen am Tag. Wir schießen Tag und Nacht.
- Aber Lilli will es nicht. Sie faßt meine Hand, ich bin ja blind, und wird mit mir den Himmel suchen gehen. Lilli, sag ich, hier riecht es nach Veilchen, hier ist der Himmel. Sie läßt meine Hand los. Ich sehe sie nicht mehr. Da vorn ist eine andere Hand. Eine leuchtende Hand. Rauchgeschwärzt. Sie greift nach dem Haus mit dem Schindeldache. Die Hand wird auf einmal Mund. Sie frißt das Haus. Kaut an ihm.
- Wenn der Wachtmeister wüßte, daß ich hier so faul liege, während er Appell hält. »Ulan Bubenreuther,« wird er rufen. »Ulan Bubenreuther ...?« Niemand meldet sich. »Ulan Bubenreuther vermißt ...« Ich habe Durst. Ich möchte etwas trinken. Etwas Heißes. Ich friere. Heißen Tee.

Dass Lilli kein Pferd sein kann, ist klar; Pferde fassen keine Hand. Es dürfte sich also um eine ihm nahestehende Frau handeln, die ihm im Angesicht des Todes als Traumgestalt erscheint.

Die Bedeutung der *runden Kugel des Glücks* bleibt nebelhaft, es könnte sich allerdings um ein Element der mittelalterlichen Vorstellungswelt handeln. Zitat aus dem [Reallexicon der Deutschen Altertümer](http://www.zeno.org/Goetzinger-1885/A/Gl%C3%BCcksrad+und+Kugel+des+Gl%C3%BCcks):

> **Glücksrad** und **Kugel des Glücks**. Aus der antiken Poesie und Kunst, welche den Gottheiten des Geschickes, der Tyche, der Fortuna, der Nemesis, als Symbol ein Rad oder eine Kugel beigeben, pflanzte sich, die Vorstellung von einem Rade oder einer Kugel des Glückes in die mittelalterliche Welt fort. Die deutschen Dichter brauchen deshalb für diese entlehnte Bildung selten den heimischen Namen des Glückes, saelde, sondern gewöhnlicher das abstrakte Wort glück oder das lateinische Fortuna; auch ist nicht immer klar, ob sie sich das Rad von der Göttin rollend umgetrieben oder das Glück selber sich in Radform denken sollen. Sinnlicher noch wurde diese Vorstellung, wenn man sich das Glücksrad mit Menschen besetzt dachte, die mit ihm auf und ab geführt werden. Das Bild wurde so beliebt, dass es in die lebendige Sage überging, z.B. in die Erzählung von den zwölf Landsknechten, welche der Teufel unter der Vorspiegelung, sie würden dann weissagen und Schätze graben lernen, auf das Glücksrad lockt und sie damit zwölf Stunden lang zwischen Wasser und Feuer umdreht, bis er einen der Zahl durch die Flammen mit sich führt; Grimms Sagen, 1, 286.

Man beachte insbesondere das Motiv des Landsknechts.

Hier ein weiteres Zitat aus [Das Glücksrad und die Kugel des Glücks, Autor Wilh. Wackernagel, Zeitschrift für deutsches Alterthum , 1848, 6. Bd. (1848), pp. 134-149](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/20650105.pdf):

> DAS GLÜCKSRAD UND DIE KUGEL DES GLÜCKS.
> Die bildende Kunst und die Dichtkunst der antiken Welt geben den Gottheiten des Geschickes, der Tyche, der Fortuna, der Nemesis, als Symbol ein Rad bei oder auch eine Kugel: In Bildwerken liegen diese neben den Füßen der Göttin, oder ihr unter den Füßen und sie schwebt darauf, oder die Kugel ihr auch auf dem Haupte.

Comment: Hat es den Anschein, dass der Soldat zu Beginn der Geschichte traurig ist, weil er alles verloren hat (Tag, Nacht, Erde, Sonne, usw.)? Oder ist er traurig, weil er sie vergessen hat (nicht mehr weiß, wie sie heißen?)
Könnte es sein, dass die Glückskugel eine Art Talisman ist, der ihm am Herzen liegt?

Und noch eine dumme Frage. "Erde" - ist das Erde (Sand, Ton usw.) oder unser Planet?

Comment: @DmitryAcemonte Alles ist möglich, Klabunds Erzählung gibt keine eindeutigen Antworten. Die Gedanken des Soldaten irrlichtern sprunghaft umher. Dass die Kugel des Glücks ein Talisman ist, halte ich unwahrscheinlich. "Ich weiß nicht mehr von [...] der runden Kugel des Glücks" deutet eher darauf hin, dass seine Erinnerungen an glückliche Tage schwinden. Und "die Erde" ist meiner Meinung nach der Planet Erde, seine Lebenswelt, die im Angesicht des Todes verblasst. "Ich werde auf einem toten Engländer in die Hölle reiten" weist darauf hin, dass er sich des nahenden  Todes bewusst ist.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Hilfe! Einmal mehr bin ich davon überzeugt, dass man bei der Übersetzung eines Textes in erster Linie mit Muttersprachlern kommunizieren muss.

Comment: Was meint Klabund übrigens, wenn er "Eine leuchtende Hand" schreibt? Glänzt es? Ist es glänzend? Oder geht sie in Flammen auf? Dann verwendet er das Wort "Rauchgeschwärzt". Das heißt, sie ist durch Rauch (Ruß) geschwärzt. Aber wenn sie geschwärzt ist, kann sie dann glänzen? Könnte es sein, dass es doch brennt?

Comment: @DmitryAcemonte Ich vermute, dass es sich um ein Feuer handelt, das ein Haus verzehrt. "Da vorn ist eine andere Hand. Eine leuchtende Hand. Rauchgeschwärzt. Sie greift nach dem Haus mit dem Schindeldache. Die Hand wird auf einmal Mund. Sie frißt das Haus."

Answer (score 1):

Yes as others have pointed out you're following the stream of consciousness of a dying person for whom reality begins to fade away. So the fact that it's a confusing mess that doesn't really have a coherent structure is kind of the point.

So (1) kinda implies that fading of reality. Like if day and night would seize to exist. Which lets be honest makes no sense as you would not even have a concept of what the simultaneous absence of both day and night would be like. And because it's nonsensical he goes on trying to describe it.
Like a ship vanishing behind the horizon, like simply forgetting about things that are so commonplace that you usually CAN'T physically forget them.

So the madness, the insanity and the feverish writing style is kind of the point.

In terms of what the sphere of fortune/luck (Kugles des Glücks) should be. Well unless it's further specified we'll never know. Maybe earth itself as he's describing it's roundness right before it. But apparently it's also common to depict luck itself as a ball like this monument by Goethe:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein_des_guten_Gl%C3%BCcks#/media/Datei:Goethes_Gartenhaus_3.jpg

And it's kind of fitting image; Like due to it's perfect symmetry there's something magical about an orb, having no beginning and no end, being the same no matter the circumstances and perspectives, but at the same time it's also impossible to balance and keep it where you want it to, because a soft breeze and it's rolling away.

So the Kugel des Glücks might just be the objectification of luck itself, would need to research if that was a common concept so that a soldier might have heard about it in fairy tales or whatnot.

And the (2) part seems to be about his thought on what's next. He wants to ride away, but on what? His horse is below or next to him but that's not an option. Then thoughts of death creep into his consciousness and so thinks about heaven and hell. He doesn't think he's going to heaven but rather expects been taken to hell by his murderous deeds (riding a dead Englishmen).

But then thoughts of a female associate, likely a close relative or love interest, called Lilli, occurs and he expects her to go to heaven so that's where his thoughts turn. And these thoughts keep him captured, like as if Lilli were to hold his hands and drag him towards heaven. And upon smelling violets he assumes he must have reached heaven.

So yeah it's a feverish stream of conscious where he drifts from one thought to another not really random but also not really structured either. Maybe the world Lilli appealed to the author because he already used the name of the flower previously and used the imagery of corpses blooming like flowers.

This kind of literature usually rarely has a fixed meaning on the one hand it's supposed to be random and erratic on the other hand it's written by a person who is not insane so they might still reveal some deeper thought in their progression and imagery.

---

Wie bereits in anderen Antworten erwähnt handelt es sich hierbei Bewusstseinsstrom (zumindest sagt Wikipedia das das so heißt), eines sterbenden Soldaten. Der Umstand das dies ein verwirrendes Konstrukt ohne kohärente Strukture ist, ist also ein bewusstes Stilmittel.

Also (1) impliziert den Verlust des Bewusstseins und des Sinns für die Realität. Er beschreibt zum Beispiel das Tag und Nacht aufhören zu existerien. Was nicht wirklich Sinn ergibt, weil es ja immer entweder Tag oder Nacht oder deren Übergänge sind, aber für die Abwesenheit beider Phänomene fehlt uns ja schon ein Grundlegendes Konzept wie man sich das vorstellen müsste. Und weil es keinen Sinn ergibt, beschreibt er in der Folge wie das aussieht, also als ob ein Schiff hinter dem Horizont verschwindet, als ob man Dinge vergisst die so selbstverständlich sind das es fasst physikalisch unmöglich scheint sie vergessen zu können.

Der Wahnsinn, Irrsinn und der fieberhafte Schreibstil sind also wie gesagt bewusst gewählt.

Im Bezug auf die Frage worum es sich bei der Kugel des Glückes handelt. Nun sofern das nicht anderweitig spezifiziert wird werden wir das wohl nie erfahren. Vielleicht der Planet Erde, des runde Strukture er direkt davor erwähnt? Allerdings ist es scheinbar auch üblich das Glück selbst als eine Kugel darzustellen wie hier in einem Monument von Goethe:
[https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein_des_guten_Glücks#/media/Datei:Goethes_Gartenhaus_3.jpg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein_des_guten_Gl%C3%BCcks#/media/Datei:Goethes_Gartenhaus_3.jpg)

Und in gewisser weise ist das auch ein recht treffendes Bild. Also durch die perfekte Symmetrie hat eine Kugel ja auch etwas magisches an sich. Sie hat keine Anfang und kein Ende, sieht aus allen Perspektiven und unter allen Umständen gleich aus, gleichzeitig ist es unmöglich sie ruhig auszubalancieren denn beim kleinsten Windhauch würde sie davon rollen.

Also die Kugel des Glücks könnte auch einfach ein literarischer Versuch sein dem Glück selbst eine Objektgestalt oder eine Form zu geben. Da müsste man sich einlesen wie verbreitet diese Bildsprache zur damaligen Zeit war und ob ein einfacher Soldat in diesen Bildern gedacht hätte, z.B. weil sie aus Sagen oder Märchen bekannt sein könnten.

Und der Teil (2) scheint die Gedanken zu erkunden wie es denn weiter geht. Er möchte wegreiten, aber sein Pferd ist tot und liegt neben oder unter ihm. Also diese Option funktioniert schon mal nicht. Danach schleichen sich, nach den eher pragmatischen Gedanken, Gedanken über den Tod in seinen Bewusstseinsstrom. Also kommt er jetzt in den Himmel oder die Hölle. Und er denkt das er nicht in den Himmel kommt sondern durch seine mörderischen Taten er auf dem highway to hell ist oder in der Technik des 1. WK Richtung Hölle reitet (auf einem toten Engländer, vermutlich die Schuld symbolisierend auf Grund derer zur Hölle fahren wird).

Doch dann kommen im Gedanken an eine weibliche Person in seinem Leben, vermutlich eine Geliebte oder eine nahe Verwandte, die er Lilli nennt und da er scheinbar davon ausgeht das sie in den Himmel kommt, werden seine Gedanken in diese Richtung gezogen, so das er das gefühlt hat sie würde in von der Hölle weg und Richtung Himmel ziehen. Und nachdem ihm von irgendwo her der Geruch von Veilchen ins Bewusstsein kommt denkt er er wäre im Himmel.

Also ja er ist in einer Art Fieberwahn, wo er von einem Gedanken zum nächsten driftet. Die Gedanken sind nicht wirklich zufällig, aber er kann sie auch nicht lange genug festhalten um ihnen wirklich einen Sinn und eine Struktur zu geben.
Vielleicht hat der Autor Lilli als Name auch einfach gewählt weil er den ähnlich Klingenden Namen der (Schwert-)Lilie bereits erwähnt hatte und generell gerne Blumen als Symbole und Bildsprache verwendet, so wie die Leichen die wie Blumen aus dem Boden sprießen.

Diese Art der Literatur ist generel schwer eindeutig zu interpretieren und oftmals gibt der Autor auch keine definierte Lesart vor, es soll in der Regel bewusst konfus, sprunghaft und zufällig erscheinen, aber da der Autor selbst es ja meist nicht im Fieberwahn sondern bewusst geschrieben hat lassen sich meist dennoch tiefere Muster und Entwicklungen von Gedanken und Bildern erahnen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please consider answering in the same language as the question (here German).

Answer (score 0):

»Kugel des Glücks« dürfte für das Glück stehen, das sich auf der Erde abspielt, unter Umständen auch für die Erde selbst, wie haxor789 es schon andeutet. Denn wer stirbt, verlässt die Erde und ist damit von jeglichem Glück abgeschnitten.

Eine verwandte Stelle findet sich bei Goethe im »Faust«:

> [Aus dieser Erde quillen meine Freuden](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Seite:Faust_I_(Goethe)_104.jpg)

Comment: Ich danke Ihnen allen!